# Game Theory problem with $2n$ piles and ends at $2$ piles

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory

Let $n \ge 2$ be a positive integer. The game starts with $2n$ piles of stones, each containing a single stone.  Players $A$ and $B$ alternately merge two piles of their choice, until there are only two piles left. $A$ wins if those final piles are both even-sized; and $B$ wins if both are odd-sized. A has first move

My first instinct is that $A$ has the winning strategy, by attempting to apply the principle of variants (i.e. monovariants and invariants). However, I'm unable to find what the invariant or monovariant is in this problem to draft a general solution.

What is the answer?

Comment: Pretty clearly only the parities of the pile sizes matter.  So let $o$ be the number of odd-sized piles remaining, and let $e$ be the number of even-sized piles.  The game starts at $(2n,0)$ and ends at either $(2,0)$ or $(1,1)$, and each move is either $(o,e)\rightarrow(o-2,e+1)$, $(o,e)\rightarrow(o+1,e-1)$, or $(o,e)\rightarrow(o,e-1)$.  If all the piles are ever even-sized ($o=0$), they must remain so, giving the win to $A$; so note that $A$ wins iff $o=0$ at any point.  Can $B$ prevent this from happening?  If so, how?

Comment: The question does not state whether $A$ or $B$ has the first move.  Does it matter?

Comment: Look at it from the end game: On $A$'s final turn, there are either $0,2$ or $4$ odd piles. $0$ is already a win for her, and $2$ is also an easy win. But $4$ odd piles is a loss, as she can only leave $B$ with $2$ odd piles and $1$ even, allowing him to combine an odd pile with the even one to win. So $B$ needs to make sure there are $4$ odd piles after his previous turn. On $A$'s previous turn, there either $0,2,4,6$ odd piles. As odd piles never increase, $0$ and $2$ are already wins for $A$, and $4$ she can turn into a win. But $6$ odd piles is a loss. By now the pattern is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second player wins.

The first player must merge two odd piles, creating an even pile. The second player responds by merging an odd pile with the even pile. Originally, there were $2n$ odd piles (and zero even piles), and after these two moves, there are $2(n-1)$ odd piles (and zero even piles). Therefore, the second player can repeat this strategy until there are four odd piles and zero even piles. From here, the first player is forced to merge two odd piles, leaving the situation
$$
\text{odd}, \text{odd}, \text{even}
$$
for the second player. Then, the second player has two options, one of which ends the game with $\text{odd}, \text{odd}$, and the other which ends the game with $\text{even},\text{even}$. Therefore, the second player can force whichever ending they prefer; if $A$ goes second, she uses this strategy to force $\text{even},\text{even}$, and if $B$ goes second, he uses this strategy to force $\text{odd},\text{odd}$.